# Traefik is forwarding container ip (10.255.0.2) as remote addr in docker swarm mode

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, restriction, traefik

I'm using docker in swarm mode. I have 3 containers like in the image below.

I want to use `docker-swarm-visualizer` and `portainer` tools under subdomains like:

- portainer.mydomain.com
- vizualizer.mydomain.com

But i want to **restrict** access to these sub domains of course.

I added `traefik.frontend.rule=Host:portainer.mydomain.com` and the other labels and without restriction everything works fine.

But after I added `traefik.frontend.whitelistSourceRange=81.x.x.200` labels to my services and tried to access it from my public IP 81.x.x.200. However in trafeik logs  I see

```
time="2018-03-23T14:23:30Z" level=debug msg="source-IP 10.255.0.2 matched none of the whitelists - rejecting" ,
time="2018-03-23T14:23:47Z" level=debug msg="source-IP 10.255.0.2 matched none of the whitelists - rejecting"
```

How can i make sure that those subdomains are only accessible from 81.x.x.200 or could there be any other approach to restrict access in domain level?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED] After a little bit of research I found out whiteListing with public IP addresses were not supported yet.

But luckily I found this [commit](https://github.com/containous/traefik/commit/d2766b1b4fc653cce4ee44b66e794d744b5e9b66) seems like gonna solve my problem :) They added a new label support `frontend.whiteList.useXForwardedFor=true`.

So, I have to wait for version 1.6 to be released, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Traefik won't see the public IP that made the query, instead it sees your gateway local IP on the [docker network](https://docs.docker.com/network/).

To redirect queries to your services with subdomains you should use [matchers](https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#matchers).

You could put a label on your service like this:

```
traefik.frontend.rule=Host:portainer.mydomain.com
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your message. But I'm already using frontend.rule label. I'm looking into matchers but I couldn't find a way to match with Remote-Addr Header. Do you have an idea how can get remote ip and restrict access to subdomains ?